# Fourier Transform - Electrodynamics

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, greens-function

I'm studying electrodynamics and am looking at Fourier transforms, especially for Greens functions. Normally, Fourier transforms are given by the following:$$G(x)=\int dk\ \tilde{G}(k)e^{ikx}$$ However, in some of the functions I'm looking at, the fourier transform is given as: $$G(t)=\int dw\ \tilde{G}(k)e^{-iwt}$$ My question is, why does the sign of the power change for the time fourier transform?

Comment: It's just a convention, really, and I've seen both used. The important thing is that the sign of the argument of the exponential function in the Inverse Fourier Transform is the opposite of the sign in the Fourier Transform. As long as you're consistent with regards to which convention you pick, either choice is fine and doesn't affect your result.

Comment: @Tom but in some of the examples I'm given, the Fourier transform in both spatial coordinates and time is given by $G(x,t)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^4}\int dw\ e^{-iwt} \int dk\  \tilde{G}(k,t')\ e^{ikx}$. Does it matter that ones a minus and one is a plus?

Comment: In this case, the Fourier Transform has a negative sign for the time variable, and a positive sign for the spatial variable. This is actually important when you work in contexts of special relativity, as time and space have different signs there, so that is likely where that comes from.

Comment: @Tom That makes more sense! Thanks

Comment: If you look at a Fourier expansion $f = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\langle f,e^{inx}\rangle e^{inx} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(s)e^{-ins}ds\right) e^{inx}$, then the Fourier transform expansion makes more sense $f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)e^{-isy}dy\right)e^{isx}ds$. You can switch the positive and negative exponents in either case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's partially just arbitrary convention, but it becomes a somewhat more significant thing in the context of special relativity. There, the proper "dot product" between a frequency and vector has the sign-flip on the time component. That is to say, when it's just space, you have
$$k = (k_x,k_y,k_z)$$
$$x = (x_x,x_y,x_Z)$$
and work with 
$$x\cdot k = k_x x_x + k_y x_y + k_z x_z$$
in your Fourier transform. When you use special relativity, you want the proper time with the time counting negative, or

$$k = (k_t,k_x,k_y,k_z)$$
$$x = (x_t,x_x,x_y,x_Z)$$
and then use
$$x\cdot k = k_x x_x + k_y x_y + k_z x_z - k_t x_t $$

So when you do a Fourier transform only in time and ignore the spatial components, this negative time convention can emerge. Of course it doesn't matter in a relativity-ignoring situation, but the convention can bleed over!

Comment: That was my best guess I just wasn't sure if I was missing something else! Thanks!